# Bluetooth dongle/controller not detected. Blueman-manager not opening

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, bluetooth

I want to connect my bluetooth headsets to Ubuntu 20.04. It's getting shown in lsusb, but not shown in bluetoothctl. What am I doing wrong? systemctl bluetooth status is running.

In HCI mode, I can see it

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

```
 sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available



service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-11-03 13:02:57 IST; 16min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2456 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19029)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2456 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 03 13:02:57 akshay-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 03 13:02:57 akshay-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[2456]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Nov 03 13:02:57 akshay-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 03 13:02:57 akshay-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[2456]: Starting SDP server
Nov 03 13:02:57 akshay-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[2456]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

And

```
blueman-manager
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 13.20.20 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 13.20.20 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

It's a usb5.0 bluetooth dongle.